# Rounded bottom on appbar

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to make an appbar with a rounded bottom, like so:

[image: Rounded appbar]

How would I go about implementing such an appbar? 
I have tried reading up on the documentation for CustomPainter, but I don't feel like that is the way to go.

Comment: I improved my answer, for a pixel perfect approach

Answer (score 93, accepted):

In Flutter you can have custom shape in AppBar widget with shape property.

```
  AppBar(
    title: Text('My App'),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
        bottom: Radius.circular(30),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 33):

You can use `BoxDecoration` to add border-radius and shadow to a `Container`/`DecoratedBox`.

```
 new Container(
    height: 200.0,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.orange,
      boxShadow: [
        new BoxShadow(blurRadius: 40.0)
      ],
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.vertical(
          bottom: new Radius.elliptical(
              MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 100.0)),
    ),
  ),
```

[image]

Although you may notice : That's not pixel perfect. The border is not an actual circle, but an ellipsis. Which may be undesired.

A more realistic, but more complex approach, is to draw a circle with a radius based on the width of your screen. Which will overflow the container. And then clip it.

You'll need a few things : `LayoutBuilder`, to get the width. `ClipRect` to not paint outside the container's constraints. And `OverflowBox`, to layout a circle that is larger than it's parent.

```
class RoundedAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SizedBox.fromSize(
      size: preferredSize,
      child: new LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraint) {
        final width = constraint.maxWidth * 8;
        return new ClipRect(
          child: new OverflowBox(
            maxHeight: double.infinity,
            maxWidth: double.infinity,
            child: new SizedBox(
              width: width,
              height: width,
              child: new Padding(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: width / 2 - preferredSize.height / 2),                    
                child: new DecoratedBox(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    boxShadow: [
                      new BoxShadow(color: Colors.black54, blurRadius: 10.0)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(200.0);
}
```

**Centered on purpose, just to show how clip works[image]**

Comment: This is great thank you! One thing I don't understand though is how to get rid of the extra margin/padding at the bottom. I have tried removing the padding and making the width/height smaller. Here is a picture of the problem: https://i.imgur.com/Qjrcme1.png

Comment: change internal padding from `width / 2` to `width / 2 - preferredSize.height / 2`. It was a mistake, sorry. Fixed. You may also want to reduce the height to `200.0`\

Comment: Thank you very much! I also added the blur radius to the padding, to prevent the shadow from being cut off.

Comment: Is there a way to apply this style to all appbars ?

Comment: How to add a simple border to all appbars ??

Comment: @SatyajyotiBiswas I found this question that applies that custom border to the appbar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57123956/how-to-make-curved-app-bar-with-custom-clipper-in-flutter
But the issue there is the flicker I end up with when using `getOuterPath` and I want to show the shadow towards the end of scrolling.
Let me know if it works for you

Comment: @SatyajyotiBiswas I actually found the way to solve even that issue by overriding the `lerpFrom` as well and return my custom class itself!

Answer (score 5):

There is one simple way to achieve this using ClipPath -

1. Apply background color to AppBar
2. Create A SizedBox/Container of some height (say 240) right below AppBar in body and apply same background color
3. Use ClipPath widget to wrap that SizedBox/Container

   ```
      ClipPath(
      clipper: CustomShape(), // this is my own class which extendsCustomClipper
      child: Container(
      height: 150,
      color: kPrimaryColor,
      ),
    ),
   ```

Now create a class like CustomShape which extends CustomClipper like below

```
class CustomShape extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  getClip(Size size) {
    double height = size.height;
    double width = size.width;
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, height - 50);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(width / 2, height, width, height - 50);
    path.lineTo(width, 0);
    path.close();
    
    return path;
 }

  @override
    bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) {
    return true;
 }
}
```

Change your heights fraction, I kept heights-50 for a nice curve you want

The output is like below -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can get the exact output by this:

```
AppBar(
    toolbarHeight:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4,
    leading: Container(),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.vertical(
        bottom: new Radius.elliptical(SizeConfig.screenWidth, 56.0),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Your above helped me a lot, I am just struggling with one thing, and that is to make the rounded bar a lot smaller in its height.

I change the height in this line

```
 Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(200.0);
```

but it doesn't affect it enough, i even set it down to 0 and still the bar is to high.

Comment: Never mind solved it by placing the above in  a stack

Answer (score -1):

***Works like a charm:***

Make the ***AppBar*** Shape property using this:

```
  const RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
        bottom: Radius.circular(30),
      ),
    );
```