# how to make curved app bar with custom clipper in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-appbar

hi i am new to flutter,

I am trying to make this app bar this is my final goal
[image: goal]

I tried to follow some tutorials to make curved app bars
but i couldn't get to the same result as i want

after some googling i could've do this simple curve
[image: simple] 
here is the clipper code i used

```
class CurvedClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - 30);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width / 2, size.height, size.width, size.height - 30);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

here is my question
is there anyway to convert svg curve to this curve clipper?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To build something similar - you'll need at least 2 quad beziers and one cubic.

I've made an example of how to achieve a result that looks mostly like the one on the image, but it might need some more fine-tuning to fit your needs.

The code has no comments provided, but you can get the idea by just changing the variables and refreshing the app (You need at least basic knowledge of how bezier lines work).

[image: Result]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          shape: CustomShapeBorder(),
          leading: Icon(Icons.menu),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),onPressed: (){},)
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomShapeBorder extends ContinuousRectangleBorder {
  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {

    final double innerCircleRadius = 150.0;

    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, rect.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(rect.width / 2 - (innerCircleRadius / 2) - 30, rect.height + 15, rect.width / 2 - 75, rect.height + 50);
    path.cubicTo(
        rect.width / 2 - 40, rect.height + innerCircleRadius - 40,
        rect.width / 2 + 40, rect.height + innerCircleRadius - 40,
        rect.width / 2 + 75, rect.height + 50
    );
    path.quadraticBezierTo(rect.width / 2 + (innerCircleRadius / 2) + 30, rect.height + 15, rect.width, rect.height);
    path.lineTo(rect.width, 0.0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }
}
```

Comment: not exactly as i wanted but i think i can take it from here thanks ^^

Comment: i want to ask you something if i have the svg of this bar is there anyway to make this easier

Comment: You can use the flutter shape maker to make this.
You just put your svg on the flutter shape maker and it gives you a CustomPainter dart class of your svg file. Then you just have to use the created customPainter on a CustomPaint widget.
Like this:
CustomPaint(
size: width,
painter: CustomPainter(),
)

https://fluttershapemaker.com/