# Image with rounded bottom corners

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-layout, rounded-corners

I'm trying to add bottom rounded corners to the image. I wrapped my image in a ClipRRect and gave it a border radius. Below is what I was able to do: [Image with border radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0xge.jpg)

However, I want the image to look something like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl8ZK.jpg)

Below is my code :

```
AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
        width: width,
        height: imageHeight * height,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(100),
          ),
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/bg_login.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Maybe this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242087/rounded-bottom-on-appbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
         Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.elliptical(
                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5, 45.0),
                  topRight: Radius.elliptical(
                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5, 45.0),
                ),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  image: AssetImage("images.jpg"),
                ),
              ),
            )
```

This should work with an animated container as well.